# Maximize $f(x,y) = x^4y^8$ on the unit circle, with $x,y\ge0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, optimization, proof-explanation

Is anyone able to explain why my solution to the following problem is not correct?

> Maximize $f(x,y) = x^4y^8$ on the unit circle, with $x,y\ge0$

Clearly $f(x,y) \ge 0$ for any $x,y\in\mathbb R$, and thus on the unit circle a maximum will occur when neither $x$ nor $y$ are $0$. So, consider the case where $x\ne0, y\ne 0$. Then, we set $$f_x(x,y) = 4x^3y^8 = 0,$$ $$f_y(x,y) = 8x^4y^7 = 0,$$ which implies that $$4x^3y^8 = 8x^4y^7 \implies y=2x,$$ since $x\ne0,y\ne0$, we may divide through by $x$ and $y$. Since we are on the unit circle, we substitute this value into $$x^2+y^2 = 1$$ $$x^2 + (2x)^2 = 1$$ $$x^2 + 4x^2 = 1$$ $$5x^2 = 1$$ $$x = \sqrt{1\over5}$$ $$\implies y = 2\sqrt{1\over5}.$$

According to [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize%20f(x,y)%20%3D%20x%5E4y%5E8%20on%20x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D1), the point on the unit circle is supposed to be $$\left({1\over\sqrt3},{\sqrt{2\over3}}\right).$$ Logically my steps seem alright, but I just can't quite figure out what happened. One of the students I TA for brought me this question and it just bugged me that I could never resolve it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think I see the error now. I should've used $x^2+y^2 = 1$ to get $y^2 = 1 - x^2$ and then substitute that into $f(x,y)$ and THEN maximize from there.

Comment: Differentiating $f(x,y)$ without the constraint $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ can give you points that are not necessarily on the circle. The maximum on the circle may not satisfy $f_x = 0$ and $f_y = 0$. But if you set up a parametric function (say in polar coordinates) and differentiate w.r.t the angle of rotation $\theta$, then set the derivative to zero, you'll get the right answer.

Comment: If $4x³y^8 = 0$, and $8x^4y^7 = 0$, this does not imply $4x^3y^8 = 8x^4y^7$, which is what you used to find $y = 2x$. Instead, the obvious solution to the system is 0, 0, which is the only saddle point in your function. The problem is that no saddle points lie on the unit circle, so this method can't be used.

Comment: Instead, a unit circle can be parameterized by y = sin(t), x = cos(t). Do this, and you are optimizing a single variable function.

Comment: You could also use Lagrange's multipliers to solve the results.

Comment: @Rohan, this is definitely possible, but the unit this problem was in was prior to the introduction of the Lagrange multiplier. Thus, I felt like it was better practice to demonstrate the solution of the problem without the use of the Lagrange multiplier.